# Pass variable in join query in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I want to pass the variable `$mid` in join query at `join('movie_genre','movie_genre.movie_id=$mid');`
it does not work.

```
$this->db->select('movie_details.movie_id,movie_details.title,movie_details.producer,movie_details.director,movie_details.writer,
       GROUP_CONCAT(movie_genre.genre) As genre, movie_genre.movie_id');
        $this->db->from('movie_details');
        $this->db->join('movie_genre','movie_genre.movie_id=$mid');

        $this->db->group_by('movie_genre.movie_id'); 

        $result=$this->db->get();
        return $result->row_array();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->join('movie_genre','movie_genre.movie_id='.$mid);
```

Use `echo $this->db->last_query();` for printing out the last query.

**Note:** `$mid` should be something like `table_name.column_name`

Comment: no, $mid is not like table_name.column_name
but,it is some id like $mid=371

Comment: First join with the `table_name.column_name`. you know how to these two tables are related, right? Then, use `$this->db->where('table_name.column_name', $mid);`. Makes sense?

Example: First: `$this->db->join('movie_genre','movie_genre.movie_id= movies.id');` Then: `$this->db->where('movies.id', $mid);`

Comment: i know this is old, but what about sql injection in this solution ?