# selecting a colum from joined tabels in database Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to select column name `level_name` from table `levels`,
which contains `level_id` and `level_name`,
for a user to know what is their level,

The table of users named as `users` and contain a `level_id` and `user_id`,
but I get this error ->

Column 'level_id' in on clause is ambiguous

```
SELECT `level_name` 
 FROM `levels` 
   JOIN `users` ON `level_id` = `level_id` WHERE `user_id` = '9'
```

**here it is the code in the model**

```
public function level_ownprofile($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('level_name');
    $this->db->from('levels');
    $this->db->join('users', 'level_id = level_id');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return  $query;
}
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: The answer here has the answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/2788333/2959769

Comment: this wont work in codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

```
Select l.level_name 
FROM levels l
JOIN users u
ON u.level_id = l.level_id 
and u.user_id = '9'


public function level_ownprofile($user_id)
{
$this->db->select('level_name');
$this->db->from('levels');
$this->db->join('users', 'levels.level_id = users.level_id');
$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return  $query;
}
```

Comment: Look here at answer but focus on the 2nd comment under it ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104314/pass-variable-in-join-query-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Change the query to

```
SELECT `level_name` 
 FROM `levels` l
   JOIN `users` u ON `u`.`level_id` = `l`.`level_id` 
 WHERE `user_id` = '9'
```

if you like the table name aliasing method, it is shorter and easier to read.

Or

```
SELECT `level_name` 
 FROM `levels` 
   JOIN `users` ON `users`.`level_id` = `levels`.`level_id` 
WHERE `user_id` = '9'
```

If you prefere to use the full table name everywhere.

Because both tables contain a column with the name `level_id` the query analyser need to know which one you are addressing.

In codeigniter try

```
public function level_ownprofile($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('level_name');
    $this->db->from('levels l');
    $this->db->join('users u', 'u.level_id = l.level_id');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return  $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function level_ownprofile($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('l.level_name');
    $this->db->from('levels as l');
    $this->db->join('users as u', 'l.level_id = u.level_id');
    $this->db->where('l.user_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->results();
}
```